# Qt: button - going back from "help.cpp" to "mainwindow.cpp"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new at Qt. I've created small application and I created second page `help.cpp`. On `MainWindow.cpp` I have a button, that switches to `help.cpp` page.

Function which switches to "help" page:

```
void MainWindow::on_box1button_clicked()
{
   helpwindow = new help(this);
   helpwindow->show();
}
```

This code works properly.

On the "help" page I've got a `QButton`, which will switch back to `mainwindow.cpp`. How Can I code that button to actually make this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention by "switching" is hiding one window and showing another one, so you can simply pass a reference of the main window to your help window and there when you want to switch back, you can hide/close itself and show the main window.

**MainWindow** (this code is fine)

```
helpwindow = new help(this);
helpwindow->show();
```

**HelpWindow**

When you want to switch back to the main window, you can do this:

```
// Hide the HelpWindow itself
// or this->close()
this->hide() 

// Show the MainWindow (i.e. the parent window)
QWidget *parent = this->parentWidget();
parent->show();
```

Comment: you can get a pointer to the parent window using something like `qobject_cast<QWidget*>(parent())`

Comment: @Mike Oh you're completely right, I just forget about it!

Comment: Works perfect. Just one more thing: how I can set up "mainWinRef"?
this->hide() is easy, but what do I have to do to make for example mainw->show()?

Comment: For sure it will work fine, but how can I implement it to the code? Direct pasting isn't working for me ('parent' cannot be used as a function'). I'm just new in the Qt and the whole programming.

Comment: @allin0n3 Updated my answer.it's `parentWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a new help(this); on mainwindow it is better to close the help window

Use 
    this->close();